# Ski rental software

Tags: point-of-sale

I am looking for a cross-country ski rental software with the following features:

- Multiples categories of customer (adults, students, kids, family)
- Can manage inventory
- Only for employees (like a POS - customers will never interact with the system)
- Cost based on a rent time
- No reservation needed

I'm having really hard time finding a solution!

I'm open concerning the platform: it can be either OS or web based. I don't have a big budget as we are a non-profit but again, I am open. Also, as we are only open 4 months a year, seasonnal pricing would be a plus.

Comment: Hi - did you find anything?

Comment: No I didn't, we will keep doing as usual with paper and pen

Comment: A drupal module https://www.drupal.org/project/merci can help you with this. I have used version 7 in past, and can enter full answer if you want to go the route of self-hosted web-based apache/php/mysql solution. It can run on internal network if internet not needed.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thank you for your suggestion!